# Are Buddhists really a type of Hindus?

Tags: vishnu, avatars, vishnu-purana, buddhism

Gautama Buddha was the 9th avatar of Lord Vishnu. Buddha himself was a Kshatriya and he was the founder of Buddhism. But he was a Hindu and he had created his own religion. So, does this mean Buddhists are a type of Hindus?

Comment: it depends. Strictly speaking, they may not be part of hinduism, because they choose not to be. However several saints have acknowledged about the underlying similarity between Buddhist teachings and Hindu Vedanta tradition. From a spiritual point of view, all religions are brothers and sisters, all help one to attain Moksha or Self-realization. All the best